# How do I pass parameters to constructor multiple times

Tags: c++

Below gives only the 1st parameter list, (4,5); the 2nd (5,8) does not work. Please suggest.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class Rectangle
{
public:
Rectangle(int length, int breadth)
{
cout << "Area = " << length * breadth << endl;
}
};

int main()
{
Rectangle rect(4,5); //WORKING
Rectangle rect(5,8); //NOT WORKING
system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: change your variable name ?

Comment: You're using classes the wrong way. If you need to only calculate the area you should define a good old C function or a static method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call:

```
Rectangle rect(4,5);
```

You're defining a `Rectangle` accesible through the `rect` variable . If you call:

```
Rectangle rect(5,8);
```

after the first definition it's going to throw an error (`rect` already defined).

Instead you have to use two different variable names:

```
Rectangle rectA(4,5);
Rectangle rectB(5,8);
```

Unluckly this is not a smart way to solve the problem, in my opinion: it's bad practice to fill memory for stuff like this.

## SOLUTION 1

#### Low memory footprint

I have to say that this is not the proper way to do a `Rectangle` class. I suggest storing the information as private and using spearate methods to calculate the area:

```
class Rectangle {

private:
int _length;
int _breadth;

public:
Rectangle (int length, int breadth) {
  _length = length;
  _breadth = breadth;
}

Rectangle (Rectangle old) { //copy old Rectangle
  _length = old._length;
  _breadth = old._breadth;
}

int area () {
  return length * breadth
}

void printArea () {
  cout << "Area = " << area() << endl;
}

};
```

Now you can do:

```
rect = Rectangle(4,5);
rect.printArea();
rect = Rectangle(5,8);
rect.printArea();
```

## SOLUTION 2

#### No memory footprint

You can use a simple function:

```
void printArea (int length, int breadth) {
  cout << "Area = " << length*breadth << endl;
}
```

This simply prints the area and doesn't store anything in the memory. If you don't need to access `length` and `breadth` again there's no point in storing it!

Answer (score 4):

The second one needs to be<sup>1</sup>

```
rect = Rectangle(5,8);
```

Otherwise you are attempting to declare a variable of the same name more than once in the same scope. That's not allowed in C++. Alternately, give the second `rect` a different name, or use at least one scoping block

```
{
    Rectangle rect(4,5);
}
{
    Rectangle rect(5,8);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, this uses the constructor you provide, and the compiler generated assignment operator.